# Can a missing glossary entry generate Warnings instead of Errors?

Tags: glossaries

The hyperref package, when it tries to link to a label that doesn't yet exist, gives a warning but continues without making the link. Is it possible to have a similar setup with the glossaries package? For example, if I use \gls{boat} could it be configured to just print  "boat" without linking to a glossary entry if such an entry does not exist?

I would like to work on the project and include \gls{} commands as I go, and then write all the glossary entries later.

Comment: You could just not load `glossaries` while writing and say `\newcommand*{\gls}[1]{#1}` and then switch when you have written the entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the [glossaries-extra](https://ctan.org/pkg/glossaries-extra) extension package you can use the package option `undefaction=warn`, which will generate a warning instead of an error message if any entries are undefined. As with `\cite` and `\ref`, it will display `??` in the document text.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[undefaction=warn]{glossaries-extra}

\begin{document}

A \gls{boat}.

\end{document}
```

This generates the warning

```
Package glossaries-extra Warning: Glossary entry `boat' has not been defined on
 input line 7.
```

The result is just

> A ??.

If you want the label to appear instead of `??` you can redefine `\glsdoifexists` to locally change `\glsxtrundeftag` to the label:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[undefaction=warn]{glossaries-extra}

\renewcommand{\glsdoifexists}[2]{%
  \ifglsentryexists{#1}{#2}%
  {%
    \edef\glslabel{\glsdetoklabel{#1}}%
    {% scope
       \let\glsxtrundeftag\glslabel
       \glsxtrundefaction{Glossary entry `\glslabel'
       has not been defined}{You need to define a glossary entry before
       you can reference it.}%
    }%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

A \gls{boat}.

\end{document}
```

This may have some unwanted side-effects. It might be better to add some markup to highlight that the entry is undefined when proof-reading. For example:

```
\renewcommand{\glsdoifexists}[2]{%
  \ifglsentryexists{#1}{#2}%
  {%
    \edef\glslabel{\glsdetoklabel{#1}}%
    {% scope
       \def\glsxtrundeftag{[?\glslabel?]}%
       \glsxtrundefaction{Glossary entry `\glslabel'
       has not been defined}{You need to define a glossary entry before
       you can reference it.}%
    }%
  }%
}
```